# Embedding Kudos in Emails

Tags: widget, html-email, user-feedback

I run an email course and I send out a lesson once in two days. The only analytics that I have been able to get so far is by looking at the email opens - which so far is a nice number, but it doesnt give me a provision to get feedback (and also a lot of people have trackers disabled).

I'd like one of the two things:

1. A survey embeded within the email that gives a quick rating of the lesson - in which case I'll get some indication of how to tweak the lesson further. Or
2. at the least a kudos widget so that i atleast know of people who read till the end, and care to give a kudos, which means i got a reaction. Based on opens against kudos received that should be an indication of lessons that need to be finetuned.

Question: Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Survey forms in email are not supported in all browsers (especially the Outlooks) so it really is not a good idea to have a survey in the email, especially as you are teaching about email. Could be embarrassing.

2.) I am not sure what you mean by "Kudos widget" but below are a couple options:

- Make a button or link to send to a survey on a landing page (can use Survey monkey or something similar for free)
- Attach to your Facebook or similar social media with a 'like' or 'follow' or even your website or blog and track the clicks.

Implementation of all of these options depends on what Email Service Provider you are using or if you are sending out through your personal email client.  Each can accept varying degrees of HTML/CSS as well as personalization.